# How to remove redundant type qualifier solution wide?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Throughout our solution we have redundant type qualifiers like the following:

```
using Project.Folder;
...
Project.Folder.Enum enum = Project.Folder.Enum.Option;
```

I am looking for a way to find and remove all the `Project.Folder.`'s that are redundant (some won't be). Is there any tool other than Resharper that is capable of this mass refactoring?

Comment: `tool other than Resharper`?!?!  what is this madness?  Seriously though, why not resharper?

Comment: My trial period has expired, I need this done ASAP, and my company hasn't gotten back to me about getting a license

Comment: That is unfortunate.  Perhaps its time to invest in your own career.  I wish I had an answer for you, but I dont really, maybe find and replace.  Also, questions asking for a favorite tool are off topic for SO, because answers are too opinionated.

Comment: This isn't about a favorite tool. This is asking about any tool that can accomplish the job. How is this any different than any other automated refactoring question?

Comment: `cntrl` + `shift` + `h` gives you replace for all solution

Comment: Unfortunately I need a little more intelligence than a find and replace can do.

Comment: I suppose you could clear out your registry and install the trial again, but you would feel much better just owning your own copy.  I know I did.

Comment: Search `Project.Folder.` and then fix the compiler issues. Or replace each item instead of doing Replace All. You can also install CodeRush for another tool trial. Or just confirm what you've always known, these tools are worth their money.

Comment: I just want to make sure you know I'm well aware that these tools are worth the money. As a student, however, I do not plan on wasting my money purchasing a license to hold me over for a few days while I wait for my co-op employer to purchase one. Nor will I use my personal copy at work because that is both unethical and violates the terms. I appreciate that you think you are educating me, but could we keep future comments directed at solving the problem only, and not hinting at my moral/ethical/whatever failings?

Comment: You may install ReSharper 8.1 EAP http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+8.1+EAP and you will have another 30 day trial

Comment: @paqogomez: Answers that suggest not answering, because the answer *might* be opinionated, are themselves opinionated. I think this SO policy is wrong (after all, opinionated readers can vote down what they think are opinionated answers). I'm amazed to find how many SO people just quote the party line.  Imagine how the OP feels: he asked a perfectly good question and somebody shows up saying he shouldn't be allowed to get an answer.  Bad SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future questioners, note that in Visual Studio 2019, you can do this similar to Resharper. Right click on a refactoring suggestion and there should be a "fix in entire Solution" option.

[image: VS 2019 solution-wide refactor]

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to use resharper I would just ctrl + shift + h and replace with nothing and then try to build - the list of errors will let you double click through to each one and you know exactly how to fix it. Time consuming but probably the only easy way forward.

Answer (score 1):

I suffer the same with R file and resources for redundant qualifier names and I do this:

<kbd>Cntrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Fill "search box" with your package.R

```
com.yourpackage.R
```

Fill "replace box" with

```
R
```

Them see results and click replace with the references you want

For me is the fasted workaround for now, hope someday the option cleanup code do it for itself